# Problem accessing a static field of a Java class

Tags: java, static, interop, clojure, field

I am having an inexplicably hard time doing something that I thought was simplicity itself. I have a JAR file on my classpath. I'm in Emacs, using a SLIME REPL, and I'm trying to access a static field of an instance of a Java class (one inside the JAR).

Here's my class:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements WindowListener,
        TreeSelectionListener {
    JPanel panel;
    InfocardWindow infoWindow;
    InfocardBuilder infocardBuilder;
    Main infomlFile;
    static NotecardModel setupModel;
    ...
```

When I tried:

```
infwb.cardmaker> (import 'javax.swing.JFrame)
javax.swing.JFrame
infwb.cardmaker> (import 'org.infoml.infocardOrganizer.MainFrame)
org.infoml.infocardOrganizer.MainFrame
infwb.cardmaker> MainFrame/setupModel
; Evaluation aborted.
```

The error message was:

```
Unable to find static field: setupModel in class org.infoml.infocardOrganizer.MainFrame
  [Thrown class java.lang.Exception]
```

I tried switching to a simpler problem: accessing a non-static field. I did it inside a `let`, to eliminate the possibility that doing this from the REPL might be the source of the problem:

```
infwb.cardmaker> (let [mainFr (MainFrame.)]
  (println (.panel mainFr)))
; Evaluation aborted.
```

The error message was:

```
No matching field found: panel for class org.infoml.infocardOrganizer.MainFrame
  [Thrown class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

I got the same result when substituting `(.panel mainFr)` and `(println (. mainFr panel)` in the body of the `let`. Also, no change when switching the REPL to namespace `user`. (Granted, these are shake-a-dead-chicken voodoo desperation moves.)

Google queries like 'emacs slime clojure unable to access Java class field error "Unable to find static field"' yield nothing useful--most have to do with trying to call Java class methods (not access Java class fields).

Just to be thorough, I tried:

```
user> (let [mainFr (MainFrame.)]
  MainFrame/setupModel)
; Evaluation aborted.
```

The error message was, as before:

```
Unable to find static field: setupModel in class org.infoml.infocardOrganizer.MainFrame
  [Thrown class java.lang.Exception]
```

Bottom line: Given an instance of MainFrame, what do I need to do to access either a static or non-static field? Thanks for any help or hints you can provide.

Comment: aren't you missing the `public` modifier? at the moment, in order to access `setupModel`, you need to be in the same package.

Comment: Yes, your problem seems to be scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) tutorial. You'll find that you need to either use the `public` modifier, or be aware that since there is no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package.

Comment: As soon as you said it, a long-lost memory fragment about Java surfaced and said, "And you said you'd always remember me!" Many thanks to all.

Comment: @Gregg Williams You should mark this as correct if it's the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements WindowListener,
50                  TreeSelectionListener {
51          JPanel panel;
52          InfocardWindow infoWindow;
53          InfocardBuilder infocardBuilder;
54          Main infomlFile;
55          static NotecardModel setupModel;
            ...
}
```

The field is not publicly accessible.  Read the [source](http://infocardorgnizr.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/infocardorgnizr/InfocardOrganizer-0_7/source/org/infoml/infocardOrganizer/MainFrame.java?view=markup).  You need to use the public modifier.